# PHP redirects not working after switching to VPS

Tags: php, .htaccess, header, vps

Edit: This issue was fixed by turning "output_buffering" to "on" in php.ini on vps server. Thank you.

After moving from shared godaddy server to managed VPS on godaddy, the PHP header redirects stopped working on the website.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    @header("Location: dashboard.php");
}
```

Any of these header redirects do not work any more.

Do you know which modules need to be installed or settings that need to be changed for this to work again? It was working fine on the shared server, and also it was tested on another server and worked fine. Just this VPS did not work. It is using WHM cpanel with easyapache 3.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: don't use `@`. It's the (childish) programming equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you". If your code is having trouble, then deliberately telling the code to shut up is, to say the least, absolutely counterproductive.

Comment: Removed the @. Yes, it shows this on the error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at public_html/index.php:1) in public_html/index.php on line 6

Comment: who needs Netflix for this entertainment :p

Comment: whats on that line???

Comment: This is on the 6th line header("Location: dashboard.php");

Comment: check if you got an empty space before "<?", or a linefeed. In index.php line 1

Comment: Thanks, checked and there are no empty spaces.

Comment: Same for the ending tag `?>` if this is being included or used anywhere else. You can even just remove `?>` to save a hassle

Comment: @user3293279 did you sent any data (like echo, var_dump, etc...) to the user before you are modifying the header? Also if you are including this file check if the scripts you are including this file in for any thing that sends output to the user before you are modifying the header.

Answer (score 0):

"Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP"
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a problem with session, not header function.
I'd suggest you to try sending header without any condition, and if it works, make sure that *session.save_path* is writable.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by turning "output_buffering" to "on" in php.ini on vps server. Thank you.